# a script to remux all MTS files in dir with mkvmerge?

Tags: linux, shell-script, matroska

I need to remux all the files present in a directory into matroska container .mkv. with a script.

I'm new to mkvmerge!

edit:
in mkverge gui this works well for me, loading just one file:

```
"mkvmerge" -o "/media/.../00062 (1).mkv"  "--forced-track" "0:no" "--forced-track" "1:no" "--forced-track" "2:no" "-a" "1" "-d" "0" "-s" "2" "-T" "--no-global-tags" "--no-chapters" "(" "/media/.../00062.MTS" ")" "--track-order" "0:0,0:1,0:2"
```

I haven't figured out yet how to get this into a bash script to run on all files in a directory.

these did not work

```
FOR %%A IN (*.MTS) DO mkvmerge -o "~nA.mkv" "%%~A"
```

.

```
for file in *.MTS; do $file `mkvmerge -o $file.mkv`;done
```

Edit 2:
didn't work because of bad syntax!  This DOES work!

```
for file in *.MTS; do `mkvmerge $file -o $file.mkv`;done
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the manpage? Please try something first and come back with a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, removed my downvote. Well done for figuring it out, why don't you post your solution as an answer and accept it (just remove the backticks (`) around the command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script works fine, something similar to an ffmpeg script I've used:

```
#!/bin/bash  
for file in *.MTS; do mkvmerge $file -o $file.mkv;done
```

just have to call that something like remux.sh and make executable, chmod +x

then I call it with a right-click Thunar custom action in the dir with MTS files, i.e. with custom action command /home/username/remux.sh %F and the Appearance condition *.MTS